# fontawesome package deforms orginal font style

Tags: fontawesome

Why do I notice a shift and deformation in the fonts when I use the fontawesome package.
The firs image doesnt use the fontawesome package and the font looks thicker and neat, when the package is included its thinner.
MWE 1: without fontawesome pack:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}

\reversemarginpar
%\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %%includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            %marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            %marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            %margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            %includemp]{geometry}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PDTOOLTIP & FONTAWESOME DECLARE %%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfcomment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fontawesome} % add skype, FB and Gtalk symbol. Has a problem.
%\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}} % add skype symbol.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End DECLARE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Research Interests}
\textbf{Complex adaptive systems in control systems engineering and
behavioral science:} distributed algorithms, computational agent-based
modeling, hybrid dynamic systems, decentralized decision making,
emergence and self organization, amorphous computing, autonomous
systems, control, communications, verification, cooperation,
optimization, game theory, resource allocation, parallel computation,
robotics, energy systems, sustainability in the built environment,
behavioral ecology, engineering education, bio-mimicry and
bio-inspiration
\end{document}
```

[image: without fontawesome package]

MWE 2: With fontawesome pack.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}

\reversemarginpar
%\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %%includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            %marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            %marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            %margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            %includemp]{geometry}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PDTOOLTIP & FONTAWESOME DECLARE %%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfcomment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % add skype, FB and Gtalk symbol. Has a problem.
\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}} % add skype symbol.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End DECLARE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Research Interests}
\textbf{Complex adaptive systems in control systems engineering and
behavioral science:} distributed algorithms, computational agent-based
modeling, hybrid dynamic systems, decentralized decision making,
emergence and self organization, amorphous computing, autonomous
systems, control, communications, verification, cooperation,
optimization, game theory, resource allocation, parallel computation,
robotics, energy systems, sustainability in the built environment,
behavioral ecology, engineering education, bio-mimicry and
bio-inspiration
\end{document}
```

[image: with fontawesome package]

Comment: Please show us your code! All questions should include a Minimal Working Example. The code used to generate that image, for example, as a small, complete document. Or any similar minimal document illustrating the problem.

Comment: See my answer. I get pretty much the opposite effect from the one you claim to get. Either you have switched things in your question or something else is going on. Impossible to say, really, without the code...

Comment: Have added the MWE with the corresponding outputs.

Comment: OK. `fontawesome` requires `fontspec` which requires Xe/LuaLaTeX. Yet you are loading `fontenc` and `times`. `times` is deprecated anyway and ought not be be used. But neither should its replacement if you are using `fontspec`. Moreover, you almost certainly don't want `fontenc` unless you know exactly what you are doing. Summary: I am not surprised you are getting odd output. You are doing all kinds of strange and mutually contradictory things with fonts in your preamble.

Comment: yes but the idea is to get the kind of output I have shown in MWE1. What package can I use to get that and still have fontawesome running successfully ?

Comment: So you just need to load a times-like font using the facilities of `fontspec`. See my edited answer for an example using TeX-Gyre Termes. Xits is also Times-like. Or you could use a system font e.g. Times, Times New Roman etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fontawesome` loads `fontspec` and `fontspec` changes the default font from Computer Modern to Latin Modern.

Computer Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: CMR]

Latin Modern with `fontspec` via `fontawesome`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: LMR]

Latin Modern via `fontspec` without `fontawesome`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: LMR again]

In the context of your code, what this means is that when you load `fontawesome`, you are getting Latin Modern:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{fontawesome} % add skype, FB and Gtalk symbol. Has a problem.

\begin{document}
\section{Research Interests}
\textbf{Complex adaptive systems in control systems engineering and
behavioral science:} distributed algorithms, computational agent-based
modeling, hybrid dynamic systems, decentralized decision making,
emergence and self organization, amorphous computing, autonomous
systems, control, communications, verification, cooperation,
optimization, game theory, resource allocation, parallel computation,
robotics, energy systems, sustainability in the built environment,
behavioral ecology, engineering education, bio-mimicry and
bio-inspiration
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern]

To obtain a Times-like font, try something like the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{fontawesome} % add skype, FB and Gtalk symbol. Has a problem.
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont
  [ UprightFont = *-Regular ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  ]
  {TeXGyreTermes}

\begin{document}
\section{Research Interests}
\textbf{Complex adaptive systems in control systems engineering and
behavioral science:} distributed algorithms, computational agent-based
modeling, hybrid dynamic systems, decentralized decision making,
emergence and self organization, amorphous computing, autonomous
systems, control, communications, verification, cooperation,
optimization, game theory, resource allocation, parallel computation,
robotics, energy systems, sustainability in the built environment,
behavioral ecology, engineering education, bio-mimicry and
bio-inspiration
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX-Gyre Termes]

If you have Times or Times New Roman installed for your system, you could use those instead. Or else choose one of the other Times-alike TeX fonts which is available in opentype.

Comment: Is it possible to capitalize the section heading using \scshape for TeXGyreTermes font ?

Comment: Yes. That should work just as it would do otherwise. The fonts support small caps (`smcp` feature) and `fontspec` makes that available. Just try `\textsc{whatever}` to confirm it. (I just did this.) No additional configuration is required.